# Conversion from px to dp for Google nexus 7

Tags: android, nexus-7

I am new to tablet application development. I am having Google Nexus7 with screen resolution (600 * 960 dip) So I want to know is it fall in to mdip category?
According to that 1px = 1dp (baseline). But If I follow this its not looks good on tablet. I am creating separate layout folder for nexus7 `-sw600dp` and mention sizes according to mdip but it not working. My images also not looking good. What I want to know what is actual conversion rate for google nexus 7. Need help.

Comment: use this link it will help:http://www.xcubelabs.com/dpi/index.html

Comment: I found this very useful: http://dpi.lv/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Formula: `pixels = dips * (density / 160)`

The Nexus 7 is 800x1280 with a 213 px density, which means it's resolution code is `tvdpi` (which means you can have a folder called `drawable-tvdpi`).

You can measure available screen size, minus window decorations, with:

```
this.getResources().getConfiguration().screenWidthDp;
this.getResources().getConfiguration().screenHeightDp;
```

On my N7, it returns 600 dp w, 888 dp h. Following the above formula, 888 dp height is 1280px - window decoration.

Comment: thank you for help. you mean if i want to define layout with 50px then equivalent dp will be                 `dp = (50 / 213) * 160` right?

Comment: That's correct. If this helped, please mark the question as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, give pixel value to below method it will give you result in dp.

```
public int convertSizeToDeviceDependent(int value) {
            DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
            return ((dm.densityDpi * value) / 160);
        }
```